# Underscore's similar functions: _.contains vs. _.some and _.map vs _.each

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Is there a reason to use one over the other? It seems that _.some and _.map are easier to use or applicable to more situations (from my very limited experience) but from reading it, they sound as if they should do the same thing. I'm sure there are other instances of this and I'm all ears on learning some of the comparisons.

Comment: Look at the return values from those functions, they are not the same.

Comment: I've noticed that from use. I'm not always clear as to why that is though I'm starting to dig into the source code a bit to learn more.  I'm really wondering if you may help generalize either performance or the situations that favor one over the other.

Comment: All of those functions are abstractions for different kinds of loops, and recursion. The differences can be subtle, but they all have a specific use case, even if for some things you can use them interchangeably.

Comment: There are no questions here that cannot be answered by reading the documentation--no need to delve into source for this. It's hard to see how to answer this question other than by just regurgitating the documentation,which is essentially what the answer here does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`_.contains` vs `_.some`**

[**`_.contains`** `(_.contains(list, value, [fromIndex])`](http://underscorejs.org/#contains)

> Returns `true` if the value is present in the list. Uses `indexOf` internally, if list is an Array. Use `fromIndex` to start your search at a given index.

[**`_.some`** `(_.some(list, [predicate], [context]))`](http://underscorejs.org/#some)

> Returns `true` if any of the values in the list pass the predicate truth test. Short-circuits and stops traversing the list if a true element is found.

The main difference between `_.some` and `_.contains` is that, `contains` checks if a given item is present in the given list and `some` checks if any of the elements in the list satisfies the predicate passed. So, they both are doing different tasks.

**`_.each` vs `_.map`**

[**`_.each`** `(_.each(list, iteratee, [context])`](http://underscorejs.org/#each)

> Iterates over a list of elements, yielding each in turn to an iteratee function.

[**`_.map`** `(_.map(list, iteratee, [context])`](http://underscorejs.org/#map)

> *Produces a new array of values* by mapping each value in list through a transformation function (iteratee).

[`_.map`](http://underscorejs.org/#map) calls the function passed (`iteratee`) with each and every element of the list to create a new Array object, but [`_.each`](http://underscorejs.org/#each) simply calls the function passed (`iteratee`) with each and every element (Note: this doesn't create an Array).

Basically `_.each` is the functional equivalent of `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {...}`. Again, they both are doing different jobs.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I'm looking for, details like_. map creates an array and _.each doesn't and you can search fromIndex with _.contains where _.some is predicate comparison. Any other details are all for the better.

Answer (score 5):

I think @thefourtheye's answer explains enough, but I thought that adding an example may help as well.

## `_.contains` vs `_.some`

The big difference here is that `_.contains` allows you to provide a value and an index, while `_.some` allows you to provide a predicate.

So, for example, let's say we have an array with the first 10 numbers `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`, how do we check if the array **contains** the number 5?

We can use the `_.contains` function:

```
_.contains([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 5); // True
```

We could use the `_.some` function as well, but it's a bit longer:

```
_.some([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], function(num) {
  return num === 5;
}); // True
```

But, let's say we need to check if the array contains any even number? It's hard to do that with `_.contains` but with `_.some` you could do something like this:

```
_.some([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], function(num) {
  return num % 2 === 0;
});
```

So yeah, there's a difference here, while `_.contains` is primarily used to check if an array contains a specific element, `_.some` could be used to check if an array contains an element with specific requirements.

## `_.each` vs `_.map`

Both these loop through the entire array, but they both have a different meaning. With `_.each` it's quite simple, you can loop through an array:

```
_.each([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], function(num) {
  console.log(num); // Will print each number
});
```

The `_.map` function on the other hand allows you to return something, it allows you to **map** an array to a new array. Let's say you want an array of every number, multiplied by 2, well, you can do that with `_.map`:

```
var newCollection = _.map([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], function(num) {
  return num * 2;
});
console.log(newCollection); // Will contain the numbers 2, 4, 6, 8, ...
```

Yes, you could do that with an `_.each` loop as well by doing something like this:

```
var newCollection = [];
_.each([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], function(num) {
  newCollection.push(num * 2);
});
console.log(newCollection);
```

But `_.map` is just a short and easier way of doing that.

Comment: I actually just got insight into this while building/testing my code. _.some had worked simple enough and contains didn't work given the way I wrote it.  Later, I had to compare a value against an array and it showed how contains could be easy and beneficial and I went back and changed the _.some version which would also need to handle similar situations

Answer (score 3):

**1) _.contains vs _.some**

I think, it is possible to say, that _.contains is special case of _.some.
That is,

```
_.contains( list, value )
```

is a shortcut for

```
_.some( list, function ( el ) { return value == 3; })
```

The second variant is just too verbose.

In [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) such useful shortcuts presents in many functions, for example:

```
var users = [
    { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
    { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false }
];

_.contains({ 'user': 'fred', 'age': 40 }, 'fred');
```

or

```
_.filter(users, { 'age': 36 });
```

**2) _.map vs _.each**

These functions are just different. _.map used for collection transformation. If your input has size of N, result of _.map also has size of N. In other words, _.map is *expression* - use it when you need to transform each element of input collection.
_.each is just a shortcut for the *for* loop. It is useful, because you don't need to calculate length of array as in

```
for (var i = 0, len = myArray.length; i < len; i++ ) {
}
```

When you use _.map or _.each properly, you declare explicitly your intentions.