# Implement `[1,2].contains(2)` in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, list, integer, contains

Essentially I require:

```
if( [1,2].contains(2) ) {...}
```

I am surprised that I can't find a simple solution to this.

Is it possible to add a `contains` method to JavaScript's List type?

[Underscore's similar functions: _.contains vs. _.some and _.map vs _.each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28759010/underscores-similar-functions-contains-vs-some-and-map-vs-each) offers:

```
_.contains([1,2], 2);
```

However, _ is JQuery, and it is still rather clumsy.

Comment: Everybody is posting the simple `indexOf` method for arrays - here are the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: Nobody has yet hit the nail on head -- is there any way to use exactly the syntax I specified?

Comment: So you want the function to return a `boolean`? You could simply do this then (if you insist): `Array.prototype.contains(i){ return this.indexOf(i) >= 0; }` and call it with `[1,2].contains(1)`. But thats just an extra work around for an answer you can essentially get quicker without wrapping it. (Edit: oh shit theres an answer saying that already)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution of Tushar is right, but I would recomend do it this way:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'contains', {
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    value: function(val) {
        return this.indexOf(val) !== -1;
    }
};
```

The reason for that is that many libraries depend on the construction

```
for (var i in array) ...
```

If you define your function without setting enumerable property to false, then all such cycles would eterate through your function as well. Enumerable = false prevents that.

Comment: Thats actually a nice thing to mention. I rarely use this and I don;t know how supported it is today but it is certainly good to know.

Answer (score 4):

You can take advantage of [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```
Array.prototype.contains = function(el) {
    return this.indexOf(el) > -1;
};

if([1, 2].contains(1)) { // Usage
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
if([1,2].indexOf(2) != -1){
```

Comment: Try `if([1,2].indexOf(1))`

Answer (score 2):

Modern browsers have [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), which does exactly that; this is in the new(ish) ECMAScript 5th edition specification, but it has been in several browsers for years. Older browsers can be supported using the code listed in the "compatibility" section at the bottom of that page.

[jQuery has a utility function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) for this:

```
$.inArray(value, array)
```

It returns the index of a value in an array. It returns -1 if the array does not contain the value.

jQuery has several useful [utility functions](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities).

An excellent JavaScript utility library is [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/):

- [`_.contains(list, value)`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#contains), alias `_.include(list, value)` (underscore's contains/include  uses [indexOf](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#indexOf) internally if passed a JavaScript array).

Some other frameworks:

- Dojo Toolkit: `dojo.indexOf(array, value, [fromIndex, findLast])` [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/indexOf.html). Dojo has a lot of utility functions, see http://api.dojotoolkit.org.
- Prototype: `array.indexOf(value)` [documentation](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Array/prototype/indexOf/)
- MooTools: `array.indexOf(value)` [documentation](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Native/Array#Array:indexOf)
- MochiKit: `findValue(array, value)` [documentation](http://mochi.github.io/mochikit/doc/html/MochiKit/Base.html#fn-findvalue)
- MS Ajax: `array.indexOf(value)` [documentation](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/Reference.Array-indexOf-Function.ashx)
- Ext: `Ext.Array.indexOf(array, value, [from])` [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.Array)

Notice that some frameworks implement this as a function, while others add the function to the array prototype.

---

**[SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript)**

Answer (score 1):

```js
if ( [1, 2].indexOf(2) != -1 ) {
  alert("2 is contained in [1, 2]"); 
}
else {
  alert("2 is not contained in [1, 2] (which is paradoxal...)"); 
}
```

Here is a simple way to check it with [array.indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Try the JQuery `$.inArray(array,vale)` function

```
$.inArray([1,2], 2)
```

It returns the index of a value in an array. It returns -1 if the array does not contain the value.

Comment: It might be better to use the javascript native implementation of `indexOf `though.

Comment: You're right, but the first answer that came to mind was that.